# How can I effectively utilize more than 4 skills per category in my build?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

The game allows you to put points into as many active abilities per category as you like, but it will only allow you to put 4 abilities on the melee skill wheel, and 4 on the ranged skill wheel.

Is there a way to effectively use more than 4 skills from 1 category, without going into the menu and remapping them constantly before or during a fight?

For example, is there some sort of quick-menu that will allow selection of all active skills?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a way to have a second set of melee abilities. You can switch between the two wheels by activating the melee ability wheel (e.g. LB/L1 on consoles), and pressing the switch button (D-Down on consoles).

The second wheel is locked behind story progress, though. I've explained how to unlock this below, but be wary of spoilers!

> Once you obtain the main story quest **Memories Awoken**, you will unlock the Forge. This allows you to upgrade the Spear of Leonidas using **Mysterious Fragments**, which are obtained from killing cultists. After completing this quest, your spear will be level 2, and you will receive a quest to upgrade your spear to level 3. Once you have upgraded it to level 3, you will unlock the second melee ability wheel.